# Accidently installed kali the wrong way

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot, bootloader

I was running windows 10 on my hp probook 6450B, i decided to install kali linux on my laptop as well. there were two hard drives shown one with 150gb that the c drive was on and another with like 780gb that nothing was on i then got a linux iso to usb program and installed the kali linux to the 780gb thing (not sure if it a partition or not) and restated my computer.

my computer then booted into the kali install menu and i went to do a graphical install but there was a problem mounting the CD drive stuff so i aborted the installation and deiced to look it up on line. when i went to go reboot my computer it only reboots into the kali menu i have tried booting from every device that i can and still no luck i cannot boot back into windows it only lets me boot into the kali menu. plus i cant even install kali because of the CD issue. i am able to get into kali live mode thats it.

would a nice wipe of the entire drive do the trick then reinstall windows and install kali the right way?

Comment: Don't forget to come back and to up-vote and accept an answer if it was useful to you. It helps you, those trying to answer your questions, and the community at large. That's also how we say 'thank you' around here :)

Comment: Well, I guess this post was made by a [Help Vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)... beware.

Answer (score 0):

> would a nice wipe of the entire drive do the trick then reinstall
>   windows and install kali the right way?

If wiping the drive as you suggest is not a problem, then re-installing should get you going.

If you're trying to get a dual-boot system to work, you'll need to install GRUB2. I've done this with Kubuntu, which offers to install it as part of its own installation process, so you need to check if Kali does this, too.

At least in my setup, I have both installed to the same physical HDD, so the only thing I needed to do during the install process was to shrink the Windows partition in order to install Kubuntu into the newly freed space.

If you're using multiple drives, the process might change because a drive that you used to have as a data drive may now also be considered bootable and have different flags set in its MBR/GPT.

***Before you wipe anything***, you should consider looking at the BIOS and the boot priority of the drives you have. It's likely that the Kali drive shows up before your Windows drive, which would not have been a problem before because it was simply a data drive with no bootable flags and OS in it.

Comment: I'd be nice if people who go around down-voting actually explained themselves.

Comment: Ok, I will wipe the drive. I have already checked the boot order and everything is fine so it's not that. How do you suggest I go about wipe the drive? DBAN or just delete all the partitions with the feature in the windows install disk?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't provide enough information

Comment: Also, I tried just wipping the Linux partition then it said it could not boot. There are three partitions left to wipe I'm going to wipe one at a time because I don't want to necessarily delete all my files if there is hope I can save them. But if I must I will delete them just a small loss that is due to my mistake

Comment: Ok deleted all partitions turned out that it was all just partiotns there is only 1 hard drive in that laptop. Created a partition at 500gb for Windows and there is another unallocated space at 490gb for Kali.

Comment: Now we wait for Windows to install and update to Windows 10

Comment: @ZedoPomart: Remove the partitions and create a new one during your install process. To make it easier, you might want to leave enough free/unpartitioned space in the drive for when you try to install your 2nd OS. Note that deleting the partitions does not actually *wipe* (or destroy) data.

Comment: that's what I did, thank you so much for all your help! It's much appreciated!

Comment: @ZedoPomart: Got it. It seems I opened the page and posted while you were still writing other comments, so I didn't see you had already done that.

Comment: it is fine I understand

Comment: @ZedoPomart: Clarifying an earlier point. The term "wipe" generally refers to overwriting data to destroy it. Deleting the partitions will certainly make your data difficult to recover w/o more specialized tools -or impossible if the new install has written to old locations.

Answer (score 0):

Before you wipe, if you are able to enter Kali, check the HDD you have on it.  Check whether you still have C with Windows folders and files.  If you do, then the partition table or selection is incorrect.  Or on Kali, open the shell and try the following:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

or

```
# fdisk -l
```

This will show the partition and HDD in a way you can check whether you still have Windows, and it is only matter of changing the partition to be active to boot from there.

***Important:*** Are you using lilo on Kali?  If so, you can change the conf file to set the Windows partition to boot from.